# Update column values by removing values after decimal points and comma in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column which stores values as `6,983.80`, `12,287.73`, `6,977.00`

so I want to update the above values with `6984`, `12288` and `6977` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `ROUND` function for that.

```
select ROUND(CAST(REPLACE('6983.80', ',') as number)), ROUND(1.4), ROUND(1.5), ROUND(1.6) from dual;
```

yields 1,2,2.

In your case, as your input is `NVARCHAR2`, it would be

```
update table1 set col1 = CAST(ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(col1, ',') as NUMBER)) as NVARCHAR2(6));
```

Please save numbers as a number type and not as string to avoid complicated castings

Documentation is [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/round_nbr.php)

Comment: getting error as `Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number`

Comment: Please add your exact DB version then (12c, 18c, 19c) and what type of column your values are as they do not seem to be of `number` type

Comment: The column is of `nvarchar2` datatype

Comment: @hud see the updated answer. Please try to save numbers as `NUMBER` type (in your case that should have been `NUMBER(7,2)` or `NUMBER(5)` then)

Comment: yes, thanks Chriz.. upvoted also